# Hash-Key URL Parameters?

Tags: url, hash, url-rewriting, ip-address

How does a url of this type get generated:

```
http://www.foo.bar/#/project/123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript:

```
location.hash = "/project/123";
```

And then when the application loads check for the hash, and redirect the user to the "hashed" url.

```
if(!!location.hash) {
    location.href = "http://foo.bar" + location.hash.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess files you can set up Rewrites (if you're using Linux). On Windows machines, you would be using IIS to do the re-writes.

Refer to [this page](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) for more info